# Kotlin - I get error beacuse id is null. How to fix it?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to make a program which will display color that you choose. So you would slide on picture with color shades and application would display you current color. Under that there is text view that will display RGB value of current color. But when I tried to write code for color picker I get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.leds/com.example.leds.MainActivity}:
java.lang.NullPointerException: color_picker must not be null
```

I tried everything but i can't fix it.

My kotlin code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var bitmap:Bitmap

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    color_picker.isDrawingCacheEnabled = true
    color_picker.buildDrawingCache(true)

    val wheel = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.color_picker)

    wheel.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
        if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            bitmap = color_picker.drawingCache

            val pixel = bitmap.getPixel(event.x.toInt(), event.y.toInt())

            val r = Color.red(pixel)
            val g = Color.green(pixel)
            val b = Color.blue(pixel)

            selected_color_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(r,g,b))

            color_value.text = "RGB: $r, $g, $b"
        }
        true}
```

And my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/color_picker"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="450dp"
    android:src="@drawable/colour_wheel"/>

<View
    android:id="@+id/selected_color_view"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/color_value"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="RGB:"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="18sp"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you did not initialize variable `color_picker` before using it

```
color_picker.isDrawingCacheEnabled = true
color_picker.buildDrawingCache(true)
```

You have to initialize it like you did in `val wheel = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.color_picker)` and then you can modify it like
`wheel.isDrawingCacheEnabled = true`

@EDIT You have to initialize variable wheel first, then you can call it's properties.

```
val wheel = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.color_picker)
wheel.isDrawingCacheEnabled = true
wheel.buildDrawingCache(true)
```

Comment: No, its not it beacuse I added id 'kotlin-android-extensions' under plugins in build.gradle. I tried your method but its still not working.

Comment: I now find out, that the problem is in that line:   color_picker.isDrawingCacheEnabled = true  , beacuse if I change here from color_picker to variable wheel, error says that wheel must not be null

Comment: but you first have to initialize variable wheel before calling it's properties/methods. Check edit in the answer

Comment: I did that and now it says:   wheel must not be null